# Nuget package creation not including referenced dlls

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, packagereference

I'm using visual studio 2019 community version and the package manager console. I am using .net core 2.2 and Package References is enabled. I want to be able to create one single nuget pack coreproj1 which will also include the dlls for Coreproj2 and coreProj3, without having to pack CoreProj2 and CoreProj3 as there are many projects and packing them all is not feasible. I've looked online and cannot find a clear solution as not many of them are using package reference

```
  CoreProj1 references CoreProj2 and CoreProj3 
  CoreProj2 and CoreProj3 do not reference anything
```

I'm currently using

```
   dotnet pack "full project path" --output "outputPath"
```

When i try to install the package i get the following error (i get the same error for CoreProj3)

```
  Error NU1101  Unable to find package CoreProj2. No packages exist with this id in source(s): LocalPackages, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org,  TestNuget   source\repos\TestNuget\TestNuget\TestNuget.csproj   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including referenced projects assemblies using the MSBuild pack targets (`dotnet pack` is effectively just an alias for `dotnet msbuld -t:pack`) [is not supported](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891). `nuget.exe pack` has a `IncludeReferencedProjects` argument that does what you wish, but does not work correctly for projects using `PackageReference` or SDK-style projects (which are always `PackageReference`).

One possible workaround is to have a build script that first build all your projects, then copies all your assemblies into a nuget package layout, and use `nuget.exe pack` to pack that directory layout.

Another workaround is to have a `nuspec` with a bunch of `<file src="..." target="lib\<tfm>\">` elements that tells NuGet to pack all the assemblies from their compiled locations.

Another workaround is to use MSBuild extensibility to tell NuGet's MSBuils targets about the assemblies you want packed after build, but before pack. There are some comments in the thread linked above giving examples how it might be done.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the repro:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>CoreProj1</PackageId>
    <Description>CoreProj1</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CoreProj2\CoreProj2.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CoreProj3\CoreProj3.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then both Proj2 and 3 have the same content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Running `dotnet pack` on the first results in a package that doesn't have the assemblies for either referenced project.

The fix is to install [NuGetizer](https://nuget.org/packages/nugetizer) (disclaimer: this was a project originally authored by Xamarin/Microsoft by myself and then sort of abandoned until I forked it and took ownership):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="NuGetizer" Version="0.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After installing it and running `dotnet pack` again, you get all three projects properly packaged. Moreover, you can also install the dotnet global tool `nugetize` so you can very quickly inspect what would be packaged, without incurring in build times:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-nugetize
```

Then just run `nugetize` from the project folder:

```
❯ nugetize
Package: CoreProj1.1.0.0.nupkg
        C:\Temp\corepack\CoreProj1\bin\CoreProj1.nuspec
    Authors    : CoreProj1
    Description: CoreProj1
    Version    : 1.0.0
Contents:
    /lib/
    net5.0/
        CoreProj1.dll
        CoreProj1.pdb
        CoreProj2.dll
        CoreProj2.pdb
        CoreProj3.dll
        CoreProj3.pdb
```

Which uses subtle coloring in the console to make it nicer:

[image]